# Как объяснить происходящее? document / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

```
document.querySelector('#msg-input').value+=12;
```

При попытке использовать данную строку кода в консоли браузера появляется ошибка:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at :1:10

Но если предварительно нажать правой кнопкой на элементе и нажать "Просмотреть код" то код становится рабочим.

Попытку выполнить код делаю после полной загрузки страницы.

UPDATE:
Оказывается внутри документа был фрейм с другим документом.

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.querySelector('#msg-input').value=11221317;
```

Comment: Попробуйте просто вывести элемент в консоль.

Comment: @OliverPatterson после загрузки страницы элемент в консоль не выводится, хотя его видно и с ним можно вполне себе взаимодействовать. НО! Если совершить ритуал нажав правой кнопкой и выбрать меню "Просмотреть код" сразу становится возможным и вывести элемент в консоль и пользоваться им как угодно.

Comment: Значит элемент ещё не загрузился, когда вы пытаетесь его получить. В каком месте вы пытаетесь выполнить код?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Пытаюсь в консоли, спустя 5 минут после загрузки страницы. Элемент явно загружен если я им пользуюсь все пять минут, Почему-то помогает только действие с исходным кодом элементов

Comment: @OliverPatterson Возможно дело в том, что элемент загружается только спустя пару секунд после загрузки основной страницы? Но как оживить его доступность в коде?

Comment: @OliverPatterson В странице содержатся несколько вложенных <!DOCTYPE html><html в отдельных iframe, возможно это как-то связано? Как в таком случае получить элемент

Comment: Не знаю насчет iframe, а насчет прошлого вопроса, нужно понимать, где это используется.

Answer (score 0):

Пишу с телефона, по этому не уверен в правильности:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', (e) =>
{
    if (e.target.id == 'msg-input')
    {
        e.target.value += 12;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что элемент находится в `iframe`. Когда вы просто открываете консоль, она работает в контексте главного окна. Но если вы щелкните на элементе внутри `iframe`, посмотрите его в дереве элементов, а потом переключитесь в консоль, она тоже переключит контекст на этот фрейм. Над полем ввода консоли находится ниспадающий список всех возможных контекстов. Если там не top, значит код запускается не в контексте главного окна.

Comment: Так и есть. Спасибо.